# Servlet Display Name Already Exists

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I'm getting this error when trying to create a servlet of the same name as one I deleted. The original one was going nowhere so i deleted it to start again, it's not in the project tree and not in the physical folder, so I can't understand why this is not working. I did refresh the project and also shut down and restarted Eclipse.

Any help appreciated. Is this some quirk of Eclipse or is there something I have to do? 
Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>first</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>contactus.html</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>adminlog.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>login</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>adlogin</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>adlogin</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: did you check web.xml?

Comment: post the exact error message & web.xml which is being referred at deployment time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take *new Servlet Class* in an IDE (eg : Eclipse), the IDE will create a `Servlet` class and configure it (`ServletClass` and `ServletMapping`) in the `web.xml` automatically.

But, even if you delete your class, the configuration might still remain in `web.xml`. Remove that configuration and create the servlet again. It should work!

Comment: Already did that, but still persists; seems to be a bug. On Eclipse Neon.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete your class, the servlet mapping stubbornly remains in the 'web.xml' file.
THerefore, the IDE misbehaves. Either change the mapping or name your servlet something different than the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet Mapping Exist In web.xml. Remove it's mapping.if you remove servlet but it's mapping  in `web.xml` , it will not allow to create same name servlet again.